# How can I make Pyspark Run on Windows after Installation

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I installed Pyspark a week ago on my windows 10 machine and everything was working fine, i even ran a sample program. However, when i tried to reload the program today, It is taking over 20 minutes just to load

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

If yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: can you please share your jupyter notebook? or code which you tried?

Comment: I have run these lines of code to import the libraries that i need to use `#Importing important Libraries
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
import json` and these load quickly but i can't create a spark context when i run this line  `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` trying to run the spark context line has taken 40 minutes so far, I am wondering why its taking a very long time

Comment: add it in the question.